# Can I copy-and-paste questions from other internet sites?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is it OK to copy-and-paste a question from another site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's never OK to copy-and-paste anything (question or answer) from another site, except with attribution.

For example, if you wanted to ask ...

> Other religions derive their ideas of right and wrong from the commandments of their god or gods. You Buddhists don't believe in a god, so how do you know what is right and wrong?

... then you should attribute the question, i.e. reference the site from which you copied the question, for example,

> [This page on buddhanet.net about the Five Precepts](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/qanda04.htm) asks the following question:
>
> > Other religions derive their ideas of right and wrong from the commandments of their god or gods. You Buddhists don't believe in a god, so how do you know what is right and wrong?

---

Also if a question is already asked-and-answered on another site then you probably shouldn't ask the exact same question again on this site. If you read the answer on the other site and still don't properly understand the answer on the other site, then ask a more-specific question about the (referenced) answer (don't just ask the same question again).

---

Copying and pasting question may be taken as a sign that you're not interested in asking a question of your own.

Please review [these answers](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=chore) for a further explanation of why a copy-and-pasted question is discouraged on this site, and multiple copy-and-pasted questions are forbidden.